# PrestaShop import module

Tags: php, prestashop-1.6

I am looking for some documentation or actually any info for creating PrestaShop back office modules (importing XML file containing list of products to database/importing CSV that was converted from that custom XML/any other way to get those products out there).

http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/User+Guide <- are the only docs I found for PrestaShop. And... to be honest: how am I to know what classes they have? What methods they offer and what they return/take as parameters?

I feel like I am missing something like: Wordpress Codex or Meteor API Docs.

This is what I think is necessary:

1. Create new back office module.
2. Create a view in the back office with
   the option to select a file from user's PC and some settings like
   product tag name, it's property names and so on (no data on that in
   the "docs" I found information only on SE/SO).
3. Use PHP's XMLReader (loading whole files is not an option I think) to parse XML and insert into database every time it recognizes a node with appropriate options. (Some knowledge about products and categories would be nice, I have found none).
4. ...profit?

It all sounds so easy when you look at it like that but I just don't know where to start with Presta.

Answer (score 1):

first try to create a basic module, prestashop is providing an online tool for creating module please [look at the tool](https://validator.prestashop.com/auth/login) and create one. The generated module have a basic config page, you can modify this and do as you want